# .toLowercase in client.on('message', async message => {

Tags: discord.js

I want my bot to respond to commands that are typen with capital letters, but where should I put it, I really don't know... :heh:. So yea where should I put the .toLowercase for my bot to respond to capital letters?

```
client.on('message', async message => {
   if(message.content.startsWith(";stats")){  
   cpuStat.usagePercent(function (error, percent) {
     if (error) {
       return console.error(error)
     }
     
     const cores = os.cpus().length // Counting how many cores your hosting has.
     const cpuModel = os.cpus()[0].model // Your hosting CPU model.
     const guild = client.guilds.cache.size.toLocaleString() // Counting how many servers invite your bot. Tolocalestring, meaning separate 3 numbers with commas.
     const user = client.users.cache.size.toLocaleString() // Counting how many members in the server that invite your bot.
     const channel = client.channels.cache.size.toLocaleString() // Counting how many channels in the server that invite your bot
     const Node = process.version // Your node version.
     const CPU = percent.toFixed(2) // Your CPU usage.
     const d = moment.duration(message.client.uptime);
     const days = (d.days() == 1) ? `${d.days()} day` : `${d.days()} days`;
     const hours = (d.hours() == 1) ? `${d.hours()} hour` : `${d.hours()} hours`;
     const minutes = (d.minutes() == 1) ? `${d.minutes()} minute` : `${d.minutes()} minutes`;
     const seconds = (d.seconds() == 1) ? `${d.seconds()} second` : `${d.seconds()} seconds`;
     const date = moment().subtract(d, 'ms').format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY');
     
     const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed() // Stable or < below than 11.x.x use RichEmbed. More than 12.x.x or Master or https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/ (github:discordjs/discord.js) use MessageEmbed.
     embed.setTitle('Axmy#0102', message.author.displayAvatarURL());
     embed.setDescription('Really non-useful bot, I know that everyone hates Axmy')
     embed.addField('Servers ', `\n${client.guilds.cache.size}`)
     embed.addField('Users ‍‍', `${client.guilds.cache.reduce((a, g) => a + g.memberCount, 0)}`)
     embed.addField('Uptime <:tired:811194778149715979>', `${days}, ${hours}, ${minutes}, ${seconds}`)
     embed.addField("Discord.js Version <:discord:811200194640216094> ", '12.3.1')
     embed.addField("CPU Usage <:down:811195966714937395>", ` ${CPU}%`)
     embed.addField("Node.js Version <:node:811196465095376896>", `${Node}`)
     embed.setColor('PURPLE')
     message.channel.send(embed)
   })
 }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick solution to your problem is this:

```js
const prefix=";";

client.on('message', async message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (!message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix)) return;

    const args=message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g); 
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command==="stats") {  
      cpuStat.usagePercent(function (error, percent) {
        if (error) {
          return console.error(error)
        }

//rest of the code...
```

But I suggest you to learn about command-handling, your codebase will look much better when you seperate commands into seperate files. There are a lot of youtube tutorials about it.